# How to format String

Tags: java, string

I can't reformat certain strings, listed below. How can I reformat these strings without printing them to the console? `System.out.printf(...)` just prints them to the console. How do I print them to my Panel?

```
public String toString() {

    // Print all stuff to the PaintShop
    String a = "five gallons container";
    String b = "one gallon container";
    String c = "one half gallon container";
    String d = "one quart container";
    String f = "one pint container";
    String g = "one half pint container";
    String s = "For this job, you need " + totalGallons + " gallons of paint. \n";
    s += "You will need to purchase:  \n";
    if (this.Five_gallons > 0 ){
        s += this.Five_gallons + " five gallons container";
        if (this.Five_gallons > 1) s+= "s";
        s += "\n";
    }
    if (this.One_gallon > 0){
        s += this.One_gallon + " one gallon container";
        if (this.One_gallon > 1) s+= "s";
        s += "\n";
    }
    if (this.Half_gallon > 0){
        s+= this.Half_gallon + " one half gallon container";
        if(this.Half_gallon > 1) s+= "s";
        s += "\n";
    }
    if (this.Quart > 0){
        s+= this.Quart + " one quart container";
        if(this.Quart > 1) s+= "s";
        s += "\n";
    }
    if (this.pint > 0){
        s+= this.pint + " one pint container";
        if(this.pint > 1) s+= "s";
        s+= "\n";
    }
    if(this.Half_pint > 0){
        s+= this.Half_pint + " one half pint container";
        if(this.pint > 1) s+= "s";
        s+= "\n";
    }   
    if(this.totalCost > 0){
        s+= "The total price is $" + this.totalCost;
        s+= "\n";
    }
    s += "Thank you for your business"; // CHANGE THIS!
    return s;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "move those string by formatting them"?

Comment: Yah what panel are you talking about exactly?

Comment: to not print `String` to console using `System.out.printf()`, use `String.format()`

Comment: I mean like nicely format those string that I listed. But I don't want to use system.out.printf(..); statement

Comment: You also want to extract a method to capture all that duplicated logic and returns a formatted substring. something like e.g. `someMethod(this.Half_pint, "half pint container")`

Comment: The fact is I've created the GUI, and I also already listed all strings above. My concern is how to nicely format those strings in that GUI.